# How to prevent the page from scrolling when dragging an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a draggable div. I want it to be only draggable within the size of my screen. But now anyone can drag it and make it go out of the boundaries.

My draggable div:

```
$("#stayaway").draggable()
```

I made a search on the web and found this line of code. It was suppose to prevent scrolling.

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden")
```

All it does is to disappear scroll bar but you can drag the div out of the window size anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`containment` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment):

```
$("#stayaway").draggable({containment: "window"})
```

### Demo

```js
$("#stayaway").draggable({containment: "window"})
```

```css
#stayaway {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: silver;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="stayaway"></div>
```

Comment: How about much smaller sizes? If I want to drag it only in a 500px x 500px square?

Comment: @K.Yazoglu See [the docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment). You can specify a selector, an element or an array defining a bounding box.

Comment: @K.Yazoglu if you resize the window and the containment element is affected you'll have to call `$("#stayaway").draggable({containment: "window"})`again to make sure it is still inside.

Comment: If you want to drag it in a 500 by 500 square, you can change the container size.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Containment`!!

```
$("#stayaway").draggable({containment: "window"})
```

> Selector: The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box
>   of the first element found by the selector. If no element is found, no
>   containment will be set.

Check out this fiddle (you can change it to a 500 x 500 square)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kpt2K/11/

Comment: How is it different from my answer?

Comment: Didn't read your answer, added a different example however. The more examples the merrier.

Comment: No worries! Hope my answer helped